# Making a macro expansion dependent on its arguments

Tags: preprocessor

I have inherited code which contains debugging macros.

```
#define DEBUG_LEVEL_NONE 0
#define DEBUG_LEVEL_ONE 1
#define DEBUG_LEVEL_TWO 2

#if DEBUG_LEVEL == DEBUG_LEVEL_NONE
  #define DEBUG(print_level, str)

#else /* DEBUG_LEVEL */
  #define DEBUG(print_level, str)                                  \
    {                                                              \
      if (DEBUG_LEVEL >= print_level)                              \
      {                                                            \
        printf("%-25s %4d %2d:", __FILE__, __LINE__, print_level); \
        printf(str);                                               \
        fflush(NULL);                                              \
      }                                                            \
     }
#endif /* DEBUG_LEVEL */
```

Everything works fine, but I would like to avoid the extra code and test for lower debug levels.

I know that I can't put preprocessor tests within macro definitions. Is there any way to get an effect like

```
#define DEBUG(print_level, str)                                 \
  {                                                             \
  #if (DEBUG_LEVEL >= print_level)                              \ 
    printf("%-25s %4d %2d:", __FILE__, __LINE__, print_level);  \
    printf(str);                                                \
    fflush(NULL);                                               \
  #endif                                                        \
  }
```

thanks

Comment: Don't forget that a multi-line macro needs backslashes at the end of each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a plain "if", any decent compiler will constant-fold the condition and exclude the body.

Comment: That is what is happening at the moment. I don't see much difference in the code size between the different debug levels.